# WPF treeviewitem selected doesn't fire (and other issues)

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I am (trying to) build a TreeView of the file system (Nodes are directories, leaves are files).

I have the xaml to do the data binding, but I cannot get the TreeViewItem selected event to fire (or I cannot detect it).

```
<Window x:Class="List.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:List"
        xmlns:dmodels="clr-namespace:List.DataModels"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

        <Window.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dmodels:DirectoryNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TreeViewItem FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Header="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Selected="TVI_Selected" >
                        <TextBlock Text="Please Wait..." MouseDown="Listbox1_MouseLeftButtonDown"  />
                </TreeViewItem>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dmodels:FileNode}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" FontWeight="Bold" MouseDown="Listbox1_MouseLeftButtonDown"  />
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="myTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" SelectedItemChanged="TreeSelectionChanged" >
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have the 'Node (directory)' displayed as a TreeViewItem (so that I can get the expander toggle), but when it is either clicked, or double-clicked, the TVI_Selected method does not get called.  When the Leaf (file)' is clicked, or double-clicked, the TreeSelectionChanged method DOES get called, but it is not a TreeViewItem (to suppress the expander toggle).

I want to intercept the Selected event so that I can replace the "Please Wait..." with the appropriate children data.

Since I am new to this, there is high probability that I am doing something stupid, or badly, or just don't get it -- if there is a better way to do any of this, I'd love to hear it.

```
private void  TVI_Selected ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    Console.WriteLine ( " TreeViewItem selection Changed " );
}

private void TreeSelectionChanged ( object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e )
{
    //Perform actions when SelectedItem changes
    BaseNode node = e.NewValue as BaseNode;

    if (node != null)
    {
        string str = node.DisplayName;
        string s2  = (node.IsDirectory == true) ? "Directory" : "File";
        Console.WriteLine ( " tree selection = {0} is a {1}", str, s2 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your problem *might* lie in your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. You're not supposed to declare an `TreeViewItem` there as the `TreeView` will automatically wrap what you define in the `DataTemplate` in a `TreeViewItem` anyway. Try removing it and defining the child items in the [`HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dmodels:DirectoryNode}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel>  <!-- Define parent items here-->
        <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}">
        <TextBlock Text="Please Wait..." MouseDown="Listbox1_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </StackPanel>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> <!-- Define child items here-->
        </DataTemplate> 
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

For more information, please see the [TreeView and HierarchicalDataTemplate, Step-by-Step](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx) page from Mike Hillberg's Blog on Wpf and Silverlight on MSDN.

Comment: thanks, but I put the TreeViewItem in the HDT because without it, I couldn't get the + (expand toggle) to display.  And if it does get wrapped, why does TreeViewItem exist?  I'm not trying to be a smartass, I am just not getting this. I will look at the link you gave -- again (I believe).  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the `+` didn't appear because you didn't define your child items? The `TreeViewItem` is there as the 'container' for the data object, like the `ListBoxItem`, or `MenuItem`. We can style and manipulate the container separately from the data content... it's very useful. For example, the containers have the ever useful `IsSelected` property so that we know which data item is selected.

Comment: Yes -- The + was not showing up because the Children (while it did exist) was empty.  Now I get the need for 'dummy' items (rather clunky, yes?).  Thank you -- I'm making (baby step) progress.  I appreciate the patience and the help.